# Is there any advantage to _.filter over _.forEach where checking one value then writing another?

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-5

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I'm leaning pretty heavily on eslint and plugins to guide me. I'm writing for an environment which has lodash 3.9.3 and must work with Chrome 40, which means es5.

I have a bit of code as follows:

```js
            _.forEach(star.system().planets, function (world) {
              if (world.starting_planet === true)
                if (world.planet) {
                  world.planet.shuffleLandingZones = true;
                } else world.generator.shuffleLandingZones = true;
            });
```

`eslint-plugin-lodash` throws up the message "Prefer _.filter or _.some over an if statement inside a _.forEach", linking to its [prefer-filter](https://github.com/wix/eslint-plugin-lodash/blob/v7.1.0/docs/rules/prefer-filter.md) article.

To my mind, `_.forEach` seems to be the right choice here, since I want to setup a new value within the existing array. But I took a crack at it and came up with

```js
            var startingPlanets = _.filter(star.system().planets, {
              starting_planet: true,
            });
            _.forEach(startingPlanets, function (planets) {
              if (planets.planet) {
                planets.planet.shuffleLandingZones = true;
              } else planets.generator.shuffleLandingZones = true;
            });
```

But I look at that and I think, isn't that just less efficient since I'm iterating two arrays now instead of one? Am I missing something? Should I be ignoring the linter on this one? Have I used `_.filter` wrong to achieve my goal?

Comment: Maybe try _.map instead?

Comment: Granted I have issues with your formatting and lack of `{}` usage in the first snippet, but that version only loops once.  I would probably prefer it.  This is my opinion, however.

Comment: Or maybe just use native array functions, forEach, map, filter and exc :) Why do you even use lodash? :D (Sorry if i disturb i'm just not a big fan of _ )

Comment: Yeah I would go for the native array methods, especially since they allow chaining like `startingPlanets.filter().foreach()`. I think eslint gives this message to encourage better code readability, although performance is decreased, but probably negligible

Comment: @HalilÇakar primarily out of habit due to having to lean on it for a number of things unsupported in native by my Chromium version restrictions. Earlier I was working with Chromium 2x. Also due to my learning off some existing code which was using lodash, so it's what I encountered first. For future work I will switch, but am sticking with lodash for this for internal consistency.

Comment: @Taplar I run Prettier with formatting, so I go with whatever it enforces or doesn't enforce and pay it no more thought. I do see though that I've been inconsistent with my IF {}, so I should fix that you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to ignore that linter warning here - `filter` should only be used when the goal is to create another array, your code is mostly fine.

> isn't that just less efficient since I'm iterating two arrays now instead of one?

Not necessarily, as lodash [implements pipelining](http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/) to avoid the creation of a temporary array. I would recommend to write this as

```
_(star.system().planets).filter({
    starting_planet: true,
}).forEach(function (world) {
    var planet = world.planet || world.generator;
    planet.shuffleLandingZones = true;
});
```